# Move pagination to footer

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I trying to move pagination to footer on my website.
I don't want to ready solution, I would like to make this alone, but I do not know where to start, how can a real programmer handle this?

*I finished this site lately from book, and now i trying to do something alone.

**code:**

```
<div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %><br/>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <%= pin.description %><br/>
        <br/>
        <strong><%= pin.user.name if pin.user %></strong><br/>
      </div>
      <% if pin.user == current_user %>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(pin) %><br/>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', pin, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="center">
  <%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
</div>
```

**screen:**

[image]

Comment: Please format your code, especially indentation.

Comment: I think it's better now, I don't know what can I do more.

Comment: The div's don't line up, that's the most important factor when debugging html code.

Comment: So now I "don't line up div's". I hope it's fine now. But friend below my post, he made a line up

Comment: This is not lining up the div's. Lining them up means using proper indentation so it's readable. You can use this tool, but any proper editor should do this automatically. http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html

Comment: ok I think now work 100%

Comment: Yeah, much better :)

Comment: Also nice one - http://www.layoutit.com

Answer (score 2):

You havent showed your containers. If you pass all content in order and into containers:

```
<div class="container"> 
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    Stff..
   </end>
  </end>
</end>
```

All should be fine. As a fast fix try to:

```
<div class="center col-md-12">
 <%= will_paginate @posts, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
 </div>
```

But this just a fast fix, not solution...

And your code is a **bit** messy, and you have one closing div, but havent showed where it was opened

Comment: I don't understand you, all of my div's have closure

Comment: Hm, now I see that yes, they all are closed. But anyway - you havent showed your containers, rows and their classes (`col-md-12` etc.) They push your elements in Bootstrap, so working on them you can solve problems with paddings

Comment: what does "you havent showed your containers, rows and their classes" mean ?

Comment: i found class ".center" in bootstraply.css.scss ? Is that what you meant?

Comment: The core Bootstrap rule is to wrap content with 'container` class, as well as other - just as in my post. Then you get your paddings and other styles without a need to code them in CSSfile. These are very first rules you learn while learning Bootstrap. I suggest to take a look at Bootstrap docs again.